# Git - show diffs across file renames with directory diff flag

Tags: git

If I rename a file and make some minor changes I can run

`git add -A && git difftool master`

which will show me a diff of each file and detect renames correctly.

However I much prefer the directory view (`-d` flag). Is there any way to get this command working properly?

`git add -A && git difftool -d master`

I am also open to other workflows, all I really want to do is be able to see diffs in files without a flood of files which have no diffs (which the first option often gives if for example a directory is renamed)

Answer (score 1):

Not perfect, but the best I've come up with

Basically I diff with the `-d` flag as my normal flow and when I want to view diffs of renamed files I drop the directory flag but use the `--diff-filter` flag to minimise clutter. I haven't yet found a way to exclude files that are only renamed (and not modified)

```
git add -A && git difftool -d master
git add -A && git difftool --diff-filter=R master
```